# Deploying Istio CNI along with VPC Native CNIS in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, amazon-eks, cni

managed k8s services like EKS and GKE provide cloud native CNIS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/pod-networking.html
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/alias-ips

we can install also deploy  service mesh like istio provided CNI in the cluster
https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/cni/

Now As part of the Istio installation,  if we deploy Istio CNI along with VPC native CNI
how would  the cluster network behave  since both CNI's are running in parallel inside the cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Istio CNI plugin actually runs as a chained CNI plugin, which means it is added to the configuration of the existing CNI plugin configured for your cluster.  It should work fine with most CNI plugins.

Comment: yes explored the docs istio cni doesn't interfere with the base CNI. https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/cni/#compatibility-with-other-cni-plugins